# How do I negotiate a salary when the offer is made via snail mail?

Tags: salary, negotiation

I have recently received a handshake offer to work a full time job at a location some hours drive away from where I currently live. A day after I tenatively accepted the job, I was informed by my hiring manager via phone that I would be sent an offer letter via snail mail that would have my salary and benefits on it. He emphasized via phone that the salary on the letter was "negotiable", leading me to believe that it will be a lowball offer.

I did not verbally agree on any salary during the interview. I was offered the job directly after the interview and I gave them a tenative start date for availability (so that they could put that start date on my offer letter), but no salary was agreed upon.

What is the best way to negotiate this amount and request other benefits such as a relocation package? Should I rewrite the employment contract with my requested amounts and send it back to them?

**Edit:** I'd like to fill in on what happened in this situation. I received the offer (it was the lowball offer I had expected) and negotiated my salary via phone, and followed up with an e-mail as advised here.

Comment: Are you sure the job posting indcated a "minimum" amount?

Comment: If no salary was mentioned, why do you think the letter will be for the minimum amount?

Comment: Yes, the job specifically stated "minimum of $X per year" on the posting. Most public sector jobs are structured in this fashion. @DJClayworth Though your question is not really relevant, I will answer it: I simply assume worst case scenario in these types of situations and plan accordingly. Perhaps I will be pleasantly suprised.

Comment: It would have been better to negotiate the salary *before* you agreed to take the job, with or without handshake.

Comment: Agreed, hindsight is 20/20. I edited the question to provide a bit more detail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wait for the letter. Read all the attached material which may include all the benefits, or information on how to view their benefits website.You may find out that the letter is required by their process, but they use an electronic system for you to submit your acceptance.

Call the contact on the letter to discuss your concerns, and ask how to proceeed. If they agree to change your pay or benefits, they will generate either a new letter and mail it or send it to you electronically.

Comment: So your answer then, is to not actually negotiate via mail and do all negotiations via phone? Please clarify this answer.

Comment: call the contact and ask how they want to proceed. They may negotiate over the phone, by email, by regular mail, or by fax. If I had my choice it would be by phone with email followup. But I am not the company.

Comment: If you are worried about the time table there is a thing called "overnight delivery".  They could also send you updates by email, you print them off, and overnight the offer to them.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: Correct. Never negotiate by mail. Call or send emails to do this.